# Getting a blank page at the start of the document after using Geometry, how can I remove it?

Tags: geometry, blank-page

I need the document to start like this:

- Cover (which is an image)
- Blank page
- Repeat cover
- Blank page
- ...

But I get a blank page before the first cover.

Here is a short working example:

Main.tex

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[a4paper,french,oneside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[pass]{geometry}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
%    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Images/} }

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \input{Pages/0.0-Cover.tex}
    \input{Pages/0.1-TitlePage.tex}
\end{document}
```

Pages/0.0-Cover.tex

```
\savegeometry{Mem}
\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
\includegraphics[scale=1,angle=0]{Cover.png}
\loadgeometry{Mem}
\clearpage
\blankpage
```

Pages/0.1-TitlePage.tex (I included this to show that in current version the first couple of page is literally repeated.)

```
\input{Pages/0.0-Cover.tex}
```

Comment: When I copy the input-files into your code, the document starts immediately with the title page, so the empty page is either caused by the fact that you input the file (maybe the \savegeometry causes a problem) or your image is too large and somehow LaTeX therefore puts it in the second page.

Comment: Look like you are right about the image being too large. When I reduce it's scale, I get the page order right. (This image is just supposed to really take the whole page...)

Comment: Then you will need to look how you really can reduce all margins to 0 … Maybe you can edit the style better with \thispagestyle, so there would be no need to save the geometry. You could also just renew the geometry after the title pages, at least if you do not need the title pages again.